# Personalized vs Standardized CV

Tags: resume, job-search, europe

In applying for a job in continental Europe (area of expertise is Computer Science). Should my CV resemble a standardized format (eg. Europass) or would a completely personalized CV give me a better chance of landing an interview?

My argument is that since the CV is nothing more than an advert for a product that I'm trying to sell, with the product in this case being myself, it should stand out from all the other candidates'. A standardized layout might make me indistinguishable from the other candidates in the interviewer's initial selection.

A counterargument though might be that my choice to not conform could be seen poorly by someone who has been in the field for a long time.

Comment: What do you mean by "completely personalized"? Personalize, yes, but don't use an "odd" layout just to stand out.

Comment: I'd definitely try to avoid coming off as odd to an interviewer. Maybe the "completely" part is a bit of an exaggeration on my part here. What i mean is just a clean looking, straight-to-the-point CV that doesn't strictly adhere to famous standards but still provides a similar level of information density.

Comment: What @Brandin says is important here. By personalize you should be wanting to mean about the *content* and not the layout. Layouts should be as sober and communication efficient as possible to avoid distracting. Expanding my answer to be more clear on this.

Comment: If you're looking for web design job, a standout CV may help. Otherwise, don't waste your time.

Comment: I would like to point out that advice on your CV's format is mostly opinion based. Different people will look at it and think different things about it. I've had recruters give me completely opposite feedback about mine. The important thing is the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your CV should:

- Look visually appealing and professional.
- Be easy to read.
- Highlight your skills and experience in the best way possible.
- Not be formatted in a fundamentally different way to the CV's of everyone else (e.g. name and title at the bottom), because people looking at your CV may have an expectation of where things should be, meaning deviating from that only makes it harder to figure out what is where and increases the chance of your CV getting thrown out.

Whether you use a standard format or a (somewhat) personalised format is unlikely to matter, as long as the above points are all true.

However, keep in mind that standard formats are standard for a reason - it has been reviewed by others and given an implicit seal of approval. When you're using a personalised format, you're likely either not having it reviewed at all, or reviewed by few people, who may not even be all that skilled in the above points.

So, it's probably better to stick to a standard format, or at least something not too different from one.

---

I'm assuming you're talking about *format* here, not *content*. Content should ideally be customised to the role you're applying for to highlight the skills, experience and achievements most relevant to the role in question.

Answer (score 1):

Content is far more likely to get you more interviews than format unless you are interviewing for a specifically design-related job. For dev job, if I saw a special design, I would probably wonder what they were missing in content that they felt they needed flash to make up for it.

Most interviewers prefer a relatively standard format because they go through hundreds or even for some jobs thousands of resumes and it makes it easier to scan quickly for content. One thing I would hate as someone who has done interviewing is ridiculous stuff like charts and graphs. Even hiring doe a data scientist, I would want to see things like that as a separate portfolio not in a resume. Don't make me take extra time to try to figure out the meaning. Meaning is critical, design is a nice to have.

If you go for something non-standard, the bar is much higher. You have to have something extremely good to be impressive, otherwise it may look childish and unprofessional which harm,s not helps, your case. Again, if you are not a professional designer, then this is likely to look bad instead of good.

Answer (score 0):

> would a completely personalized CV give me a better chance of landing an interview?

This is more likely true. Usually you want to **customize your resume for the company or position you are applying for.**

A standardized resume may leave important details out that could have been of interest for recruiters of such company. That is why you should always try to put some effort when applying, do some research on the job and company you seek, and tailor your resume accordingly.

This takes more time, but guarantees more chances of success. Besides, this way you will be getting more offers from things you actually want, instead of receiving many offers from companies you may not like so much.

A wise thing to do would be to have some **basic template or layout for your Resume, that you can then easily adapt to other jobs** you seek, thus making it as standard as possible but enabling you to customize accordingly.

*Edit:* As user Brandin commented, by personalize you should stick to the *content* and not much the *layout*. It is better if you use a sober and organized layout, one that is not distracting to the content you want to convey.

Probably if your career were Design or similar you would be expected to have an elaborated or more visually appealing resume when applying, but given your field is CS this should not be a decisive factor, so focus more on the content you should be showing.

Answer (score -3):

I would defiantly go for personalized. Anything that shows you took extra effort is a plus, so long it does not get unpractical (So stay in A4-format, and don´t use comic sans).

But, I can only talk about Germany experience here. I know this differs between countries, there is not really a EU standard.